# What are 'unaligned pkts' in MacOS `ifconfig`

Tags: networking, macos, ifconfig

While trying to track some network issues with my Mac Studio, I ran into a strange metric that I can't figure out – 'unaligned pkts', which seems to be incrementing at a rate of ~20/s.

```
> ifconfig -v en0 
en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 23
    eflags=410009c0<ACCEPT_RTADV,TXSTART,RXPOLL,ARPLL,ECN_ENABLE,FASTLN_ON>
    xflags=1<WOL>
    options=567<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,AV,CHANNEL_IO>
    hwassist=720067<CSUM_IP,CSUM_TCP,CSUM_UDP,CSUM_TCPIPV6,CSUM_UDPIPV6,VLAN_MTU,MULTIPAGES,TSO_V4,TSO_V6>
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    inet6 xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x17 
    inet 192.168.xxx.xxx netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.xxx.xxx
    netif: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    flowswitch: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (10Gbase-T <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
    status: active
    generation id: 23
    type: Ethernet
    agent domain:Skywalk type:NetIf flags:0xa443 desc:"Userspace Networking"
    link quality: 100 (good)
    state availability: 0 (true)
    scheduler: FQ_CODEL 
    link rate: 10.00 Gbps

    unaligned pkts: 43549194
    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

    qosmarking enabled: yes mode: none
    low power mode: disabled
    multi layer packet logging (mpklog): disabled
    routermode4: disabled
    routermode6: disabled
```

I couldn't find anything on Google – what are unaligned packages, and is it ok to have them at that rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could find, this is an error when sending network
packages, where message headers are not aligned on 4-byte
(32 bit) boundaries. It perhaps arrives when messages are
embedded within other protocols.

Although this is not part of the standard, software patches
were introduced in network messaging handlers for these
cases, that allow the correct handling of such packets
(outside of the standard).

In other words, this problem is signaled, but if you have no
frequent hard errors on the network, it's then handled
correctly by the networking software and there is no reason
to worry.

The source where I found the information was
[Misalignment, MIPS, and ip_hdr(skb)->version](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.kernel/c/tVbJHjS26L0).

Comment: For anyone looking for the same answer, this was an indicator that my router couldn't deal with 10 Gbps link, although it claimed so. I switched routers and the metric went away entirely. As did my network issues.